# Не работают горячие клавиши в linux в PhpStorm на русской раскладке

Tags: linux, phpstorm

В PhpStorm 2017.2 и Gogland не работают горячие клавиши при работе на Ubuntu 16.04.3

Пробовал это решение https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes, но оно не работает. Кажется, что оно работает для версии 2017.1

Подскажите, как это можно починить?

Заранее благодарю!

**UPD:**
Вопрос про русскую раскладку. На английской все норм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил новую версию 2017.3, после этого вот этот фикс срабатывает и все норм https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes

Answer (score 1):

Это, конечно, очень маловероятно, но не забываете ли Вы поменять раскладку на английскую? У меня с русской тоже хоткеи не работают.

Comment: Вопрос именно о русской раскладке

Comment: Пока что не фиксится, увы, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема Java; мы уже решили ее для Mac OSX (пропатчив JDK), но не для Linux:(
Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за [JRE-215](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-215), чтобы получать уведомления об обновлениях

Comment: Но почему у некоторых все нормально и решение https://github.com/zheludkovm/LinuxJavaFixes помогает, а мне нет?